# how to create a second aspnetusers table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two users Rec and Can who shares the same identity database for aspnetuser. I would like each of them to have a separate identity aspnetuser tables. Since that emails are both registered on the same table and the duplication of the email is not allowed even if the roles are different.

```
     public async Task<ActionResult> Create(RegisterAsCanModel registerAsCanModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = registerAsCanModel.EmailAddress, Email = registerAsCanModel.EmailAddress };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, registerAsCanModel.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Candidate");
                db.RegisterAsCanModels.Add(registerAsCanModel);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View(registerAsCanModel);
    }
```

Second method with different roles type

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create( RegisterAsReqModel registerAsReqModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = registerAsReqModel.EmailAddress, Email = registerAsReqModel.EmailAddress};
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, registerAsReqModel.Password);
            if(result.Succeeded)
            {
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Req");
                db.RegisterAsReqModels.Add(registerAsReqModel);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View(registerAsReqModel);
    }
```

if creating the same table of aspnetusers twice is not allowed than what would be the appropriate solution

Comment: As per my knowledge, aspnetusers table allows repeating emails but not usernames. You can create 2 users with same email address and different usernames

Comment: even though repeating emails is allowed that would not be the case since the email should be unique for each different user type so  how can I repeat emails just based on different user role

Comment: email and username are both required even though that still not the case

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do the following. first add the UserType to the AspNotUsers Table than

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(RegisterAsCanModel registerAsCanModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = registerAsCanModel.UserName, Email = registerAsCanModel.EmailAddress };
            user.UserType = "Candidate";
            if(db.Users.Where(m => m.Email == registerAsCanModel.EmailAddress && m.UserType == "Candidate" ) == null)
           {
                UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager)
                {
                    RequireUniqueEmail = false
                };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, registerAsCanModel.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Candidate");
                    db.RegisterAsCanModels.Add(registerAsCanModel);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        return View(registerAsCanModel);
    }
```